# Arithmetic summation question - I don't understand this answer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I'm really sorry for this basic, stupid question. I have been looking for answers online but I can't find any.

I don't understand the following summation:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i=\frac{n(n-1)}2$$

I understand that the basic formula for summations of i is the following:

$$\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

I get how to do index shifts, but I don't see how we get to the result shown above. I understand that people value quality questions in this website; I did google around and found nothing, that is why I am here bothering you.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s really just a substitution. You have the formula $$\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}2\;.\tag{1}$$ Suppose that $n=m-1$; then $(1)$ becomes

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}i=\frac{(m-1)\big((m-1)+1\big)}2=\frac{(m-1)m}2=\frac{m(m-1)}2\;.\tag{2}$$

Now just change the name of the quantity $m$ in $(2)$ to $n$, and $(2)$ becomes

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i=\frac{n(n-1)}2\;.$$

(Note that it really doesn’t matter whether the summation starts at $i=0$ or at $i=1$, since adding $0$ doesn’t affect the sum.)

**Added:** Alternatively, you can let $j=i+1$ and argue that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i=\sum_{j=1}^n(j-1)=\sum_{j=1}^nj-\sum_{j=1}^n1=\frac{n(n+1)}2-n$$

and do a little algebra to reduce this to $\frac{n(n-1)}2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brian M. Scott, but the summation I showed is starting at 0; does this alter anything?

Comment: @user115675: No, because adding $0$ doesn’t affect the sum.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @user115675: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You have $$\sum_{i=1}^n=\frac 12n(n+1)$$  If you don't like the substitution given by Brian M. Smith, you can just make the correction:  $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i=\sum_{i=1}^n=\frac 12n(n+1)-n=\frac 12n(n-1)$$ where the first equality just accounts for the deleted term and recognizes that the added term in the sum is $0$  Of course, they give the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

$2(1+2+3+4+5...+n)=(1+2+3...+n)+(n+(n-1)+....+2...+1)$.

Now add the first one in the first bracket with the first one of the second bracket, the second of the first with the second of the second and so on to get:

$(1+n)+(2+(n-1)+...(j+(n-j+1))+...+(n+1)=n(n+1)$
 since there are $n$ pairs.

so $2(1+2+3+4...+n)=(n+1)n$. which means $(1+2+3+...+n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\quad  f_1 + \cdots + f_n &=&\,  -f_0 + (\color{#c00}{f_0\! +\cdots +\! f_{n-1}}) + \color{#0a0}{f_n}\\ \\  &=&\quad 0 \,\ +\ \color{#c00}{\dfrac{n(n\!-\!1)}2}\ +\ \color{#0a0}n\\ &=&\qquad\quad\ \dfrac{n(n\!+\!1)}2\end{eqnarray}$